# Grub configuration to load cloud-init from external removable disk in Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall

Tags: boot, grub2, cloud-init, autoinstall

I'm trying to auto-install Ubuntu 20.04 from an .iso file loaded in virtual media and I would like to load the cloud-init configuration from an external device.

I've already followed this [tutorial](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/) that show how to repack a custom .iso to add on the cdrom the cloud-init configuration which lead to a grub configuration like this one :

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/server/ ---
```

I would like I don't have to repack the standard .iso file and load the cloud-init file from an external disk such as an USB key.

I'm working on a DELL server whose iDRAC allow me to simulate an external drive by mapping an .img file.

In grub console, I can acces to this device and files in it :

```
grub> ls (hd3)/cloud-init
meta-data user-data
```

What I'm aiming is something like this (which of course I tested and not working) :

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=(hd3)/cloud-init/ ---
```

I saw that during the installation the external device is available on a /dev/sdX which is not mounted unlike the /cdrom and I can't determine which sdX it will be.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to

- format the USB key as `vfat`
- give the `vfat` partition the label `CIDATA`
- put your files (e.g. `user-data` and `meta-data`) on the USB `vfat` partition

If the USB key is connected then *cloud-init* should detect it and use the files automatically.  There is no `ds=` argument required.

The current *cloud-init* [documentation for the NoCloud datasource](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/datasources/nocloud.html) has more details and an example.

> a labeled vfat or iso9660 filesystem containing user data and metadata may be used. For this method to work, the filesystem volume must be labelled CIDATA

I have not tested this.